# Return Results Which Match Multiple Queries In Laravel Eloquent Search

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get search results **where atleast 2 or 3 keywords match** in keywords array.

Example Table

| Name | Categories | Keywords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | category1,category2,category3 | keyword1,keyword4,keyword3,keyword2 |
| name2 | category4,category2,category6 | keyword6,keyword4,keyword3 |
| name3 | category5,category2,category1 | keyword2,keyword5,keyword3 |
| name4 | category7,category3,category4 | keyword1,keyword4,keyword8,keyword6 |

```
            $categories = explode(',' ,$site->category);
            $keywords = explode(',' ,$site->keywords);
            
            foreach( $categories as $category)
            {
            $results = Website::where('category', 'like',"%{$category}%")
            ->where('name', '!=', $name)  
            ->where(function ($query) use ($keywords){
                
    
                foreach( $keywords as $keyword)
                {
                    $query->orWhere('keywords','like', "%{$keyword}%");
                }
    
            }             
            )
```

Above codes returns all results that match single keyword, **Requirement **: Only results that match more than 2 keywords. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think your query is fine , I tested with `$site->category = "category2"` and `$site->keywords = "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4"` and the result will return `name1 , name2 and name3` , please do note you return same $results from multiple categories search , while I search only through single category, perhaps you can use `foreach ($categories ` inside another `->where()`

Comment: The above query works fine for each matched keyword. I want search results those match multiple keywords not one.

Comment: hello Win, I tried your suggestion of for each inside another where and it gave somewhat desired results, but still, I want to narrow down search results those have atleast 2 keywords from searched wesbsite's keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [where-subquery](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses). Something like this:

```php
Website::where('category', 'like',"%{$category}%")
    ->where('name', '!=', $name)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('count(websites.keywords)')
            ->from('websites')
            ->where('keywords', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
    }, '>', 2)
    ->get();
```